# Symlinking images so that I dont need redundant copies of images

Tags: magento-1.9

I have 2 instances of a Magento Store.

One is our production system and has the path:
/home/user/public_html/

another one is our Staging-System and has the path: 
/home/user/stage/

I want to symlink all images from production-/media to stage-/media.

I've tried it with enabeling Symlinks and simply set a symlink in the respective folder, but this does not seem to be enough.

What is needed to setup a working symlink with Magento?

Answer (score 0):

Can I just clarify your symlink process first?

In the staging directory;

Delete media on staging;

```
rm -rf media
```

Or rename it;

```
mv media mediaold
```

Create symlink (run this from root of staging site)

```
ln -s /home/user/public_html/media/ media
```

Try and load your magento, what error do you get? Can you access the images directly?

Comment: This was my Doing before which has not worked.

Comment: @max can you access images directly via the urls?